# Npm can't install any packages

Tags: node.js

I need some help because i can't install any npm packages.
When i try to install something i get this error.

[image]

My node version is 6.11.0 and npm version is 3.10.10.

npm-debug.log :

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'server:dev',
1 verbose cli   '--',
1 verbose cli   '--hot',
1 verbose cli   '--proxy-requests' ]
2 info using npm@3.10.10
3 info using node@v6.11.0
4 verbose stack Error: missing script: server:dev
4 verbose stack     at run (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\run-script.js:151:19)
4 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\run-script.js:61:5
4 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:356:5
4 verbose stack     at checkBinReferences_ (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:320:45)
4 verbose stack     at final (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:354:3)
4 verbose stack     at then (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:124:5)
4 verbose stack     at ReadFileContext.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:295:20)
4 verbose stack     at ReadFileContext.callback (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:78:16)
4 verbose stack     at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete] (fs.js:366:13)
5 verbose cwd C:\Users\Scyli\Desktop\angular
6 error Windows_NT 10.0.14393
7 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "server:dev" "--" "--hot" "--proxy-requests"
8 error node v6.11.0
9 error npm  v3.10.10
10 error missing script: server:dev
11 error If you need help, you may report this error at:
11 error     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
12 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Please help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved: 32-bit NodeJs completely solved my problem.

Comment: Thank you for existing

Answer (score 6):

I tried many different suggestions finding a solution. For reference: I'm working in Goorm online IDE.

In the end, simply reinstalling npm in the root directory did the trick. I ran:

```
sudo npm install npm -g
```

and afterwards I was able to install packages as normal again.

Answer (score 5):

This commands solve same problem

```
npm install -g npm
npm cache clean
npm update
npm install
```

Answer (score 2):

my problem solves after editing  npm-config file

for edit that file **npm config edit**

my npm config file

```
;;;;
; npm userconfig file
; this is a simple ini-formatted file
; lines that start with semi-colons are comments.
; read `npm help config` for help on the various options
;;;;


;;;;
; all options with default values
;;;;
; access=null

; allow-same-version=false

; always-auth=false

; also=null

; auth-type=legacy

; bin-links=true

; browser=null

; ca=null

; cafile=undefined

; cache=C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache

; cache-lock-stale=60000

; cache-lock-retries=10

; cache-lock-wait=10000

; cache-max=null

; cache-min=10

; cert=null

; cidr=null

; color=true

; depth=null

; description=true

; dev=false

; dry-run=false

; editor=notepad.exe

; engine-strict=false

; force=false

; fetch-retries=2

; fetch-retry-factor=10

; fetch-retry-mintimeout=10000

; fetch-retry-maxtimeout=60000

; git=git

; git-tag-version=true

; commit-hooks=true

; global=false

; globalconfig=C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc

; global-style=false

; group=0

; ham-it-up=false

; heading=npm

; if-present=false

; ignore-prepublish=false

; ignore-scripts=false

; init-module=C:\Users\Admin\.npm-init.js

; init-author-name=

; init-author-email=

; init-author-url=

; init-version=1.0.0

; init-license=ISC

; json=false

; key=null

; legacy-bundling=false

; link=false

; local-address=undefined

; loglevel=notice

; logs-max=10

; long=false

; maxsockets=50

; message=%s

; metrics-registry=null

; node-options=null

; node-version=8.11.2

; offline=false

; onload-script=null

; only=null

; optional=true

; otp=0

; package-lock=true

; package-lock-only=false

; parseable=false

; prefer-offline=false

; prefer-online=false

; prefix=C:\Program Files\nodejs

; production=false

; progress=true

; proxy=null

; https-proxy=null

; user-agent=npm/{npm-version} node/{node-version} {platform} {arch}

; read-only=false

; rebuild-bundle=true

; registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/

; rollback=true

; save=true

; save-bundle=false

; save-dev=false

; save-exact=false

; save-optional=false

; save-prefix=^

; save-prod=false

; scope=

; script-shell=null

; scripts-prepend-node-path=warn-only

; searchopts=

; searchexclude=null

; searchlimit=20

; searchstaleness=900

; send-metrics=false

; shell=C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe

; shrinkwrap=true

; sign-git-tag=false

; sso-poll-frequency=500

; sso-type=oauth

; strict-ssl=true

; tag=latest

; tag-version-prefix=v

; timing=false

; tmp=C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp

; unicode=false

; unsafe-perm=true

; usage=false

; user=0

; userconfig=C:\Users\Admin\.npmrc

; umask=0

; version=false

; versions=false

; viewer=browser

; _exit=true

; globalignorefile=C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmignore
```

Answer (score 2):

I was getting leaf signature err,so i solved it by:
//first type this

```
npm config set strict-ssl false
```

//and then

```
npm config set NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED 0
```

and after that try to install the packages.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to clear your cache and update your npm from the root of your `nodejs` installation folder.

To do that, Navigate to your, `C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm` directory and issue the below command,

```
npm cache clean
```

After than update your npm using the below command,

```
npm update
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunatelly, it didn't work, when i tried npm update i got an other Error. EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm-debug.log.120514789'
npm ERR!     at Error (native). This time with this message too.

Comment: @DócziSzilárd, Instead of using `cmder`, Kindly try these commands in `CMD` `(Start => (Type) CMD => Right Click on the displayed "CMD" entry and click Run as Administrator`

Comment: The same with it too.. Maybe something wrong with the proxy settings? i use Wi-fi, bu i read in other forums, in the proxy settings can be some trouble.

Comment: Could be.. Even antivirus programs can force these errors at times.. Check disabling them momentarily if you have one.

Comment: I have windows defender, in the proxy settings what should i set ?

Comment: Can you just turn-off your windows defender, and try executing the commands?

Comment: Solved, I has to install 32-bit nodeJs, despite of i have 64bit windows.

Comment: Kindly update your post, (or) Post this as a solution here. It will be useful for others who may face a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was cloning a GIT repo at work that other developers were using and building without issue. Tried all these solutions but the ultimate fix was downgrading my version of npm to an earlier version. Very simple, I know, but this line of code may just save you a day of debugging if your output is different than other devs on your team!

```
npm -v
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of answers were *true* or *close* but missed the mark at least on a specific use-case. If you are using the default version *provided by the package manager* then you have to remove it and install with [the NodeSource Repository](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-rocky-linux-8) for example, or the Node Version Manager.  This was the case for me with RockyLinux 8.

```
curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_18.x -o nodesource_setup.sh
sudo bash nodesource_setup.sh
rm -f nodesource_setup.sh

sudo dnf remove nodejs npm -y
sudo dnf install nodejs -y
```

Then confirm with:

```
node -v
npm -v
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are a windows user ***run cmd as administrator*** and then install packages. It worked for me while installing express via npm.

Comment: So any other solutions? You could suggest without drawbacks please